# Rspec tests failing after switching to user-scoped finders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I started learning rails by writing a small task tracking app. Now I'm trying to refactor to be a little more secure. For example, before updating or destroying, I'm now using a scope to make sure you're looking at your own task.

After doing this though, three tests are no longer passing and I'm not sure how to fix them. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change the tests or did I forget to do something with the factory?

Thanks!

```
**Task@controller**
def update
  @task = current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:id])
  authorize @task

  if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error updating the todo."
  end

  respond_with(@task) do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tasks_path }
  end
end

def destroy
  @task = current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:id])
  authorize @task

  if @task.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Todo was deleted successfully."
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the todo."
  end

  respond_with(@task) do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tasks_path }
  end
end
```

Test 1 and 2

```
**task_controller_spec**
require 'rails_helper'

describe TasksController do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before do
    @user = create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

describe '#update-completed' do
   it "updates a task to be completed" do
      task = create(:task, user: @user)
      expect( task.completed ).to eq(false)

      patch :update, id: task.id, task:{completed: true}
      task.reload
      expect( task.completed ).to eq(true)
    end
  end

  describe '#destroy' do
   it "deletes a task" do
      task = create(:task, user: @user)
      delete :destroy, id: task.id
      expect( @user.tasks.count ).to eq(0)
    end
  end
end
```

Test 3

```
**feature_spec**
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Task" do

  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  before do
    @user = create(:user)
    login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
  end

  feature "completes", js: true do
    scenario "a task using a checkbox" do
     task = create(:task, user: @user)
      visit tasks_path
      check("task[completed]")

      expect( page ).to have_content('Todo completed!')
    end
  end

  after do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end
```

which result in...

```
1) TasksController#update-completed updates a task to be completed
 Failure/Error: patch :update, id: task.id, task:{completed: true}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #    <ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation_Task:0xc1e4450>
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in `method_missing'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in `method_missing'
 # ./app/policies/application_policy.rb:26:in `update?'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/pundit.rb:70:in `public_send'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/pundit.rb:70:in `authorize'
 # ./app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:28:in `update'

2) TasksController#destroy deletes a task
 Failure/Error: delete :destroy, id: task.id
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation_Task:0xc51965c>
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in `method_missing'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in `method_missing'
 # ./app/policies/application_policy.rb:26:in `update?'
 # ./app/policies/application_policy.rb:34:in `destroy?'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/pundit.rb:70:in `public_send'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/pundit.rb:70:in `authorize'
 # ./app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:42:in `destroy'

3) Task completes a task with a checkbox
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation_Task:0xbe5fb04>
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in `method_missing'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in `method_missing'
 # ./app/policies/application_policy.rb:26:in `update?'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/pundit.rb:70:in `public_send'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/pundit.rb:70:in `authorize'
 # ./app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:28:in `update'
```

Task factory

```
 **task factory**
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :task do
      description "MyText"
      user nil
      completed false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
# Returns an ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation    
@task = current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:id])
```

to

```
# Returns a single Task instance
@task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
```

`find` docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have guessed that was the cause